# JHipster + Powermock/Mockito test cases generation

Tags: java, jhipster

I am creating a project using Jhipster, I noticed that it automatically generates test cases(structure of test cases) as well. Is there a way to generate `powermock` or `Mockito` based test cases in JHipster? Is there any such plugin available?

P.S I tried googling but most of the pages ended in Powermock/Mockito related queries

I also looked in to the JHipster mini book. It uses `mockMVC` related examples but not Mockito/Powermock based test cases.

Comment: JHipster already uses Mockito (e.g. in MailServiceIntTest), only for Spring MVC tests it uses Spring MockMVC which sounds reasonable. So your question is not very clear to me

Comment: Ya I noticed it generates test cases for Spring MVC layer but not generating test cases for the other layers for example service/business layer and for this I want to generate test case format for powermock/mockito. is it possible to automate this? Further more I would want to remove configuration from the MVC layer also I want @RunWith(PowermockRunner.class)

Comment: I doubt the team would want to add a dependency on Powermock and this looks like a big effort for a module with little benefit. So, I'd say, do it on your project and if you think it adds value, you can show your project to get some feedback from JHipster team.

Comment: Cool (y) thanks :) :)